# SQL query for select statement when certain bind parameters were entered

Tags: sql, select

I need help with a select statement. I want to use this for my search API where if you pass in certain parameters, fist Name, or last Name, or both, or first Name and state, the query will run as other parameters were not filled it.

Is there a way to do that? This is my query

```
    select d.is_purged, d.is_reorg, ds.dlr_nm, ds.city, c.first_nm, c.middle_nm, 
    c.last_nm, c.is_mdd, ds.state, lds.display_name, c.is_wrn, d.crt_ts, d.upd_ts 
    from deal d 
    left join candidate c on d.candidate_id = c.id 
    left join lkup_deal_status lds on d.status = lds.status 
    left join dealership ds on d.id = ds.deal_id 
    where (c.first_nm is null or c.first_nm  = :firstName )  
    and (d.is_purged = false )  
    and (ds.dlr_nm is null or ds.dlr_nm = :dealershipName) 
    and (ds.city is null or ds.city = :city)  
    and (c.middle_nm is null or c.middle_nm = :middleName) 
    and (c.last_nm is null or c.last_nm = :lastName)  
    and (ds.state is null or ds.state = :state)  
    and (lds.display_name is null or lds.display_name = :status)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What happens when you run the query?

Comment: when I run this query, it asked me to enter bind parameters, so I put in firstName as John and last name as Doe, nothing is pulled up from DB.

Answer (score 0):

```
    I ended up figuing it out.

   For Java: String SEARCH_DEAL = "select d.id, ds.id, ds.dlr_nm, d.bac, 
    d.is_reorg, c 
    c.first_nm, c.middle_nm, " +
        "c.last_nm, c.is_mdd, c.is_wrn, ds.city, ds.state, ds.rgn, 
    lds.display_name,  d.crt_ts, d.upd_ts " +
        "from mhdid_171749.deal d left join candidate c on d.candidate_id = c.id 
    " +
        "left join lkup_deal_status lds on d.status = lds.status " +
        "left join dealership ds on d.id = ds.deal_id  " +
        "where d.is_purged = false " +
        " and (:dealershipName::varchar is null or ds.dlr_nm = :dealershipName)" 
  +
        " and (:firstName::varchar is null or c.first_nm  = :firstName ) " +
        " and (:lastName::varchar is null or c.last_nm = :lastName) " +
        " and (:bacCode::int is null or d.bac = :bacCode)" +
        " and (:city::varchar is null or ds.city = :city) " +
        " and (:state::varchar is null or ds.state = :state) " +
        " and (:region::varchar is null or ds.rgn = :region) " +
        " and (:status::varchar is null or lds.display_name = :status) ";

For SQL: 
      select d.is_purged, d.is_reorg, ds.dlr_nm, ds.city, c.first_nm, 
      c.middle_nm, 
    c.last_nm, c.is_mdd, ds.state, lds.display_name, c.is_wrn, d.crt_ts, 
   d.upd_ts 
   from mhdid_171749.deal d 
    left join candidate c on d.candidate_id = c.id 
    left join lkup_deal_status lds on d.status = lds.status 
      left join dealership ds on d.id = ds.deal_id 
      where d.is_purged = false
     and (:firstName is null or c.first_nm  = :firstName )  
     and (:dealershipName is null or ds.dlr_nm = :dealershipName) 
     and (:city is null or ds.city = :city)  
       and (:middleName is null or c.middle_nm = :middleName) 
       and (:lastName is null or c.last_nm = :lastName)  
     and (:state is null or ds.state = :state)  
     and (:status is null or lds.display_name = :status);
```